# Unable to access Session in Action method in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, session-variables

[image: Cannot access Session in Action Method in MVC5]

I am trying to set a session variable in an action method in MVC5, but it is giving compile-time error as shown above.

**My Question**: How can i correctly set a session variable in this case? Session is enabled in web config.

Controller name is OrdersController and action method is GetOrders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that this is too simple and I was missing it.

All that is needed to set a session variable in an action method is code like below.

```
Session["ColumnFilters"] = "somevalue";
```